# Why could I skip any synchronization for DCL if I use 32-bit primitives and my function idempotent?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, primitive, idempotent

I' ve read following classical famous article: [The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

I have a question about:

> In fact, assuming that the computeHashCode function always returned
>   the same result and had no side effects (i.e., idempotent), you could
>   even get rid of all of the synchronization.

```
// Lazy initialization 32-bit primitives
// Thread-safe if computeHashCode is idempotent
class Foo { 
  private int cachedHashCode = 0;
  public int hashCode() {
    int h = cachedHashCode;
    if (h == 0) {
      h = computeHashCode();
      cachedHashCode = h;
      }
    return h;
    }
  // other functions and members...
  }
```

The article was written for java 4. Is it still valid for java 8+?

Is it true that `computeHashCode()` will be invoked only once?

Comment: You've tagged the question with `dcl`, but I don't see any connection to the Digital Command Language.

Comment: @HABO thanks, corrected. I expected that it is Double Checked Locking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it can be executed multiple times. Synchronization "flushes" the changes to other threads, and without it the changes made in one thread could theoretically never be communicated outside that thread.

But, the article doesn't say that `computeHashCode` will be called exactly once, it's just that the race condition doesn't cause any problems. `int` writes are guaranteed to be atomic, and if the `computeHashCode` is idempotent (which requires the class and its fields to be effectively final) you'll just overwrite previous values with the same value, so nothing bad happens.

Comment: The problem that article doesn't explain it at all

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't be guaranteed to be called only once, but that is irrelevant.

If `computeHashCode` is idempotent, calling it extra times has no effect and thus threads cannot interfere with each other.

Answer (score 1):

From the same article you have posted:

> JDK5 and later extends the semantics for volatile so that the system
>   will not allow a write of a volatile to be reordered with respect to
>   any previous read or write, and a read of a volatile cannot be
>   reordered with respect to any following read or write.
>
> With this change, the Double-Checked Locking idiom can be made to work
>   by declaring the helper field to be volatile. This does not work under
>   JDK4 and earlier.

which means that double-checked locking is safe starting from Java 5.

> Is it true that computeHashCode() will be invoked only once?

No. The method is not synchronized in any manner. However, it's thread-safe, since it's idempotent.